# Bug or kludge in /etc/init.d/networking

Tags: 10.04, networking, startup

There are some strange code:

```
    if ifup -a --exclude=lo; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
```

both variants have exactly same code:

```
        log_action_end_msg $?
```

Why need "if", "then", "else", "fi"?
Why not simple:

```
    ifup -a --exclude=lo
    log_action_end_msg $?
```

There are 3 times such code in this file.

This file belongs to "netbase" 4.35ubuntu3

Comment: logically it is the same

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the `if` statement appears to be unnecessary.  My guess is that the two branches of the `if` statement did different things in an older version, but the two branches were modified to their current form at some point.

If it bothers you, I'd suggest [filing a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+filebug).

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/965023